# Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context

Tags: fatal-error

Whenever we turn on testimonies from `Essential addons` setting, the whole website shuts down and we get this message.

> Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in
>   /home4/eecsydney/public_html/wp-content/plugins/essential-addons-for-elementor-lite/elements/testimonials/testimonials.php
>   on line 551

Can you please help us resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

That's for sure an update plugin error, the best thing you can do is to report to the plugin developers, they may have been aware by now but talk to them to see what happens.

When a client comes with a similar problem, I suggest to:

1. Update PHP, probably you are using 5.5.
2. Downgrade the plugins and use an older version, but stable.